# Does it look bad if I publish an IEEE journal article without "Member, IEEE" next to my name?

Tags: publications, journals, ieee, professional-association

I am the second author of three, and the only one who does not have an active membership.  I have little need for the other services provided by IEEE, as I already have access to XPLORE through my work.

Comment: Are you certain that you aren't a member?  If you've gone to an IEEE conference within the last year, you're probably a member because they tend to make membership+registration cheaper than non-member registration.

Comment: @jakebeal, maybe, maybe not. My university refuses to pay professional society membership dues even if it saves on total conference attendance costs which they are paying. This may be a funding agency rule at some agencies in the US, or it may be local to my university. I do not know.

Comment: @BillBarth Interesting: for most people I know it is standard to put it as part of their conference costs, which I suspect is why IEEE does it that way.

Comment: @jakebeal, my research indicates that NSF is vague on allowing this and NIH explicitly allows it. It may be a local rule.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope, and I doubt anyone would notice or care.

Everyone can be a member, all it takes is a bit of money.

Comment: I've never understood why people say "Member, IEEE" after their name on some papers. All it means is that they paid the fee.

Comment: @ThomasS It wouldn't surprise me if it was started/encouraged by IEEE.

Comment: @ThomasS you usually see it in Journal publications and it is the standard of presenting authors "Name, IEEE rank". Also the 'Student, Graduate and Member" ranks are a simple subscription but certainly 'Senior Members' and especially 'Fellow' ranks show recognition and contribution to the profession and the EE society.

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned, I doubt anyone cares, except if you or co-authors are Fellows, then it'll carry some weight.   It might convey the following message: the paper has been vetted and informally approved by esteemed member(s) of the IEEE and therefore all reviewers+editor should accept the paper with a grain of salt.

Comment: "a grain of salt" means read cautiously and without trusting the authors completely, which is the opposite of the rest of your answer.