# Does being a member of IEEE make it easier to publish in the transactions?

Tags: publications, ieee

We are in process of finalizing a draft for submission to a good venue for publication (Comp. Sc.). I have never published in IEEE Transactions, though I have a paper under review with one of them. I note that the majority of the IEEE articles have membership details besides the author name.

Questions:

- Do you need to be  a member of the IEEE in order to publish in one of the transactions?
- If not, do reviewers perceive articles submitted by non-members less favourably?

*Note: I am already a member of ACM and its specialized groups. I don't see any reason to join IEEE just to add something with my name in the article.*

Comment: Related: [Does it look bad if I publish an IEEE journal article without “Member, IEEE” next to my name?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/64393/does-it-look-bad-if-i-publish-an-ieee-journal-article-without-member-ieee-nex)

Comment: Is IEEE reputable? how can I know and check that?

Comment: @SSimon are you asking as a whole bunch or a specific venue sponsored or published by IEEE?

Comment: @Coder I am very confused by IEEE, I first heard it on here, this website, now my graduate school updated regulation and accept ISI, SCOPUS, PubMed and IEEE indexing, I dont understand how much they are reliable, even they claim they are peer reviewed, they seem to have low impact, but if possible I find journal that is interesting for me to publish there

Comment: @SSimon until and unless your measure of reliability and low-impact defined, it is difficult to answer. Ask as a separate question.

Comment: I cannot @Coder it is not allowed to aks about it

Comment: @SSimon When it comes to Electrical Engineering it is both the most impactful and reputable publisher. No idea why you would  think the opposite unless your field is so outside the area.

Comment: @o4tlulz what about Nano?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simple answer: no. I'm not an IEEE member and none of my coauthors are, but we regularly publish in the IEEE transactions.

Comment: +1. Thanks for the answer. Does it apply to all the domain specific transaction such as in computer science? Have you published in one of these?

Comment: The only place that looks like it is an advantage of being a member of is PNAS.

Comment: @Coder I'm not familiar with transactions on computer science, but in many years I've never heard anyone complaining about such kind of discrimination. Of course, there can be a few reviewers willing to discriminate non-IEEE members -because there can be idiots everywhere- but I'm sure they are rare.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano thanks for the probabilistic answer on the prior being low cases.

Comment: One certainly does not _have_ to be a member of IEEE. Although, if one commonly publishes in IEEE journals, then it seems that you would be involved in areas of importance to other IEEE member, a community of practice in some sense. So, why _should_ one not be a member of IEEE if you work in that area and commonly communicate with that group of folks?

Comment: I'm also not a member of IEEE and regularly publishes in IEEE transactions. You can also see some IEEE Fellows who became an IEEE member only after they received said recognition..

Comment: @JonCuster For computer scientists, IEEE and ACM have highly overlapping coverage, and often one will simply join the one whose conferences they are more likely to attend (conference registration costs for both societies are typically priced to encourage membership).

Comment: @jakebeal - No, I understand. But, if you are an ACM member and publish primarily in IEEE (or vice versa) one might want to reconsider. As a material scientist, do I join APS, MRS, AVS, ... -  well, you pick one or two and see how it goes and if you specialty veers a bit you might shift around over time.

Comment: I agree with @jakebeal ... conference discounts matter. But more to the point, I know that ACM charges less for providing open access if any author is a member.  IEEE may do the same.  I concur with those who have said it doesn't affect acceptance.

Comment: @JonCuster Also if you attend one or two conferences a year, the discount is more than your annual fees anyways.